# SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table '' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

Using the following code, I get the error that states I need to put identity insert to ON for [Tournaments].[Tournaments] and [Games].[Game]

```
 if (!context.Items.Any())
        {
            context.Database.OpenConnection();
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Items].[Items] ON;");
            Tournament Tournament = _tournamentDbContext.Tournaments.Where(x => x.Id == 1).First();
            Game _Game = _gameDbContext.Games.Where(x => x.Id == 1).First();
            ItemType ItemType = context.ItemTypes.Where(x => x.Id == 1).First();
            Item item = new Models.Items.Item
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Test",
                ItemType = ItemType,
                Price = 100,
                Short_Description = "TestShort",
                Tournament = Tournament,
                Game = _Game,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now
            };
            context.Items.Add(item);
            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Items].[Items] OFF;");
            context.Database.CloseConnection();
        }
```

If I add the code which sets both identity_inserts on:

```
  if (!context.Items.Any())
        {
            context.Database.OpenConnection();
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Items].[Items] ON;");
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Tournaments].[Tournaments] ON;");
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Game].[Games] ON;");
            Tournament Tournament = _tournamentDbContext.Tournaments.Where(x => x.Id == 1).First();
            Game _Game = _gameDbContext.Games.Where(x => x.Id == 1).First();
            ItemType ItemType = context.ItemTypes.Where(x => x.Id == 1).First();
            Item item = new Models.Items.Item
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Test",
                ItemType = ItemType,
                Price = 100,
                Short_Description = "TestShort",
                Tournament = Tournament,
                Game = _Game,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now
            };
            context.Items.Add(item);
            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Items].[Items] OFF;");
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Tournaments].[Tournaments] OFF;");
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Game].[Games] OFF;");
            context.Database.CloseConnection();
        }
```

It errors, `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON for table 'aspnet-SpidShop-FA900737-72CD-4ABA-BDEF-598D51CB5A43.Items.Items'. Cannot perform SET operation for table 'Tournaments.Tournaments'.'`

I have no idea what to do, as I'm not even changing Tournaments and Games tables, only Items. Any idea how to fix this issue?

UPDATE:

I got through the identity insert problems by deleting all migrations, disabling initialize method, then redoing the migrations.

I'm facing another problem:

```
if (!context.Items.Any())
        {
            Tournament Tournament = _tournamentDbContext.Tournaments.Where(x => x.Id == 1).First();
            Game Game = _gameDbContext.Games.Where(x => x.Id == 1).First();
            ItemType ItemType = context.ItemTypes.Where(x => x.Id == 1).First();
            Item item = new Models.Items.Item
            {
                Name = "Test",
                ItemType = ItemType,
                Price = 100,
                Short_Description = "TestShort",
                Tournament = Tournament,
                Game = Game,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now
            };
            context.Items.Add(item);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The last line throws `SqlException: Invalid object name 'Game'.`

The model:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Short_Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
    public Tournament Tournament { get; set; }
    public Game Game { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

And my context

```
 public class ItemDbContext : DbContext
{
    private string Schema = "Items";
    public ItemDbContext(DbContextOptions<ItemDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ItemType> ItemTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ItemTag> ItemTags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().ToTable("Item", Schema);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ItemType>().ToTable("ItemType", Schema);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ItemTag>().ToTable("ItemTag", Schema);
    }

}
```

Game is not null, and it gets matched properly.

Comment: First decide if you want the database to generate the keys or if your .NET Code should generate the keys, then adjust your question. There is no point in configuring identity columns in your tables if you want to set the keys yourself.

Comment: Yes, I want the keys to be autogenerated. I set them myself here, because it's the seed method. Even if I remove "Id = 1", it throws the same error.

Comment: I removed "Id = 1", and deleted IDENTITIY_INSERT ON for those 3 tables. I still get the same error.

Comment: `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` can only be active for **one table** at a time

Comment: That makes sense. I deleted all of them. I still get the same error, even though I'm not insert ANYTHING into Tournaments or Games. The error pops are SaveChanges(). Could you check the edited question?

Comment: did you recreate the database so it matches your model? This error says EF passes PK values for entries (which it only does if the model does not set the column to identity or computed), but DBMS is unable to set them since the column is still set to autoincrement.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I've gotten through that, check the update. Thanks for your help, though :)

Comment: I think you should revise the whole question now. Most of it has become irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had multiple contexts, I put all in one, and removed IDs, as they should be autogenerated.